# Not Recognized as an Internal or External Command

Tags: python, system

I am getting this error in iPython:

> 'taskset' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
>   operable program or batch file.

What needs to be done to correct this error?

```
import numpy as np
from os.path import join
from os import system,getpid
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from time import time
import cPickle
import csv
from IO import load

system("taskset -p 0xff %d" % getpid())
```

Comment: does taskset command works on your command line ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`taskset` is not a Windows command, but *"is not recognized as an internal or external command, operable program or batch file."* is a Windows error.

Are you trying to run a Python script on a Windows machine, based on commands you tested in a linux shell? If so, that's probably not going to work.

Comment: Thanks Amber...riddle solved.